# How to test a Service with a Mocked repository that has multiple other dependencies (services and repos)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I'm testing my SpringBoot Services with Mockito.

The problem is that some of the services I'm testing have multiple dependencies with other Services and Repositories which makes it difficult to perform a test on deeper levels of the Service.

For example:

The class "TestService" contains the method below:

```
public Test addTagToTest(Long id, Long tagId) {
    Tag tag = tagService.getById(tagId);
    Test test = getById(id);

    test.addTag(tag);
    return update(test);
}
```

This class has a dependency with "TagService".
Note: each Service has its own Repository.

And this is the service class which is being used by TestService:

```
@Service
public class TagService extends GenericAbstractService<Tag, TagRepo> {
    public Tag getTagByName(String tagName){
```

In my JUnit test class which contains the @Test method, I've got something like this:

```
@Autowired
private TestService testService;

@Mock
private TestRepo repository;
```

So the question is now how to test my TestService which has dependencies **which have dependencies**? All repositories must be mocked.

Comment: Are you loading the spring context for testing or just unit tests?

Comment: See the https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-jpa-test

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to mock all of them. Mocking one layer of classes is sufficient. 
Test Service is calling TagService.getById(). In this case, TagService is making a method call to a repository and getting the result. We can mock TagService.getById(). To be specific with Mockito,

```
@Mock
private TagService tagService;

@Test
public void yourTest() {
    doReturn(<tag object you want>)
            .when(tagService).getById();
}
```

In this case, TagService.getById doesn't actually get called. It directly returns what you want to return. So you don't have to worry about the repository which is autowired in TagService. Hope this helps.

Comment: You have to also remember to add @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) annotation to your class, or add method with @Before annotation that will include MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

Comment: True. I was trying to give an explanation to the question not the actual code snippet.

Comment: @476rick, if this answer works for you, can you accept it? Or if you expect something else, please update the question.